# How to correct a specific error about std::to_string?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am beginner is C++ and my codes are not the way most of programmers would code it, because I am just trying to learn C++ in high school.
I would have a question about a specific error that I am getting when I run my code.
The error is C2665 : 'std::to_string' : none of the 9 overloads could convert all the argument types.

The code is :

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
            stringValue = std::to_string(myVector[j]);
            intValue = atoi(stringValue.c_str());

            if (intValue < lowest) {
                lowest = intValue;
            }

            sum = sum + intValue;
        }
```

Could anyone correct the code in such a way that I could convert scoreAssign into a string then into an integer ?

The whole coding :

```
    std::vector<std::string> myVector;
    std::vector<std::string> ID;
    std::vector<std::string> assignment;
    std::vector<std::string> midterm;
    std::vector<std::string> final;
    std::vector<std::string> finalAverage;
    std::vector<std::string> grade;

    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("E:/C++/Projects/Textfile project/Textfile project/class_data.txt", ios_base::in); 
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            myReadFile >> output;

            char* token = NULL;
            char* context = NULL;
            char delims[] = " ,\t\n";

            token = strtok_s(output, delims, &context);

            while (token != NULL)
            {
                myVector.push_back(token);
                token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);
            }
        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();



    int numOfStudents = (myVector.size() + 1) / 10;
    int sum = 0;
    int scoreAssign = 0;
    int lowest = 100;
    int intValue = 0;
    std::string stringValue;

    for (int x = 0; x < numOfStudents; x++) {

                ID.push_back(myVector[0]);

                for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
                    //stringValue = std::to_string(myVector[j]);
                    intValue = atoi(myVector[j].c_str());

                    if (intValue < lowest) {
                        lowest = intValue;
                    }

                    sum = sum + intValue;
                }
                scoreAssign = (sum - lowest) / 6;
                stringValue = std::to_string(scoreAssign);
                assignment.push_back(stringValue);
                midterm.push_back(myVector[8]);
                final.push_back(myVector[9]);

                myVector.erase(myVector.begin(), myVector.begin() + 9);
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < ID.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << ID[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < assignment.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << assignment[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < midterm.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << midterm[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < final.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << final[i] << std::endl;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the declared type of `myVector`?

Comment: @ Mooing Duck std::string

Comment: I edited to code but still does not work..I will show my whole coding

Comment: @UtherPendragon _'@Mooing Duck std::string '_ `std::to_string(myVector[j]);` So why a conversion to `std::string` should be provided?? It makes no sense and isn't available!

Comment: Can you please give us a short complete compilable example

Comment: @UtherPendragon: When I asked what is the declared type of `myVector`, the correct answer was `std::vector<std::string>`.  (Also, we don't want the whole code.  We want a short, complete, compilable example of your specific problem.)

Comment: @ clcto I seen that the string conversion does not make sense, so I changed it...it compiles but does not work...I displayed the full code, but I do not know why it does not work

Comment: "does not work" is not specific enough for us to diagnose the problem effectively.

Comment: @UtherPendragon Do not change your questions randomly, upon possibly appearing solutions!! This would invalidate already given answers to your question!!

Comment: so myVector has all its values inside of it, I tested it before, I just want to organize those values into a few other vectors, such as ID, midterm, final and assignment ... it compiles nicely, but the specific error that I am looking for is inside the big for loop, the one that starts with for (int x = 0; x < numOfStudents; x++) { ...because it does not push_back the values inside the 4 smaller vectors

Answer (score 4):

You can't "just" stringify  vector. What  is the expected format?

Add an onverload:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(std::vector<T> const& v, const char* delim = "\n")
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(oss, delim));
    return oss.str();
}
```

Full sample **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9868cfcc2feba14)**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::string to_string(std::vector<T> const& v, const char* delim = "\n")
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(oss, delim));
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << to_string(std::vector<double> { 1.1,2.2,3e-12 }, ";") << "\n";
    std::cout << to_string(std::vector<int> { 42, -13 }, "\t") << "\n";
    std::cout << to_string(std::vector<std::string> { "42", "-13" }) << "\n";
}
```

I've chosen an 'arbitrary' format. You can adapt it to your wishes.

Comment: question has been udpated